# Error accessing Scylladb cluster outside docker container

Tags: docker, cassandra, scylla, cassandra-python-driver

I'm running Scylladb locally in a docker container and I want to access the cluster outside the docker container. That's when I'm getting the following error: cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers')

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.17.0.2  776 KB     256          ?       ad698c75-a465-4deb-a92c-0b667e82a84f  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless
```

```
Cluster Information:
    Name: Test Cluster
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSnitch
    DynamicEndPointSnitch: disabled
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        443048b2-c1fe-395e-accd-5ae9b6828464: [172.17.0.2]
```

I have no problem accessing the cluster using cqlsh on port 9042:

```
Connected to  at 172.17.0.2:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.8 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
```

Now I'm trying to access the cluster from my fastapi app that is outside the docker container.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

cluster = Cluster(['172.17.0.2'])

session = cluster.connect('Test Cluster')
```

And here's the Error that I'm getting:

```
raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.17.0.2:9042': OSError(51, "Tried connecting to [('172.17.0.2', 9042)]. Last error: Network is unreachable")})
```

Comment: Is your host machine a Mac? One of the known limitations is that you can't directly route traffic from the host to containers in a Mac. If not, then please demonstrate the relevant connection section of your Python program.

Comment: @FelipeMendes Yes my host is a Mac. Do you know of any workarounds?

Comment: Yes, run your program within a Docker container and you shall be able to route traffic to Scylla. That's a Mac limitation.

Answer (score 2):

with a little bit of tinkering, it's possible to achieve a connection to the Scylla running in a container outside of the container for local development.

I've tried on M1 Mac with docker desktop:

1. Run scylla container with couple of new parameters[[src]](https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/blob/efbfcdb97edbe63def923aae66a647f17c39f21b/conf/scylla.yaml#L83-L93):

   - `--listen-address 0.0.0.0` for simplification as we are spawning Scylla inside the container to allow connection to the container from any network
   - `--broadcast-rpc-address 127.0.0.1` required if `--listen-address` set to `0.0.0.0`. We are going to port forward `9042` from container to host (local) machine, so this is an IP where it will be acessible.

   The final command to spawn the container is:

   ```bash
   $ docker run --rm -ti \
      -p 127.0.0.1:9042:9042 \
      scylladb/scylla \
          --smp 1 \
          --listen-address 0.0.0.0 \
          --broadcast-rpc-address 127.0.0.1
   ```

   The `-p 127.0.0.1:9042:9042` is to make port 9042 accessible on host (local) machine.
2. Install [`pip3 install scylla-driver`](https://python-driver.docs.scylladb.com/stable/index.html) as it has support of `darwin/arm64` architecture.
3. Write a simple python script:

   ```py
   # so74265199.py

   from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

   cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])

   session = cluster.connect()
   # Select from a table that is available without keyspace
   res = session.execute('SELECT * FROM system.versions')
   print(res.one())
   ```
4. Run your script

   ```
   $ python3 so74265199.py
   Row(key='local', build_id='71178cf6db7021896cd8251751b78b3d9e3afa8d', build_mode='release', version='5.0.5-0.20221009.5a97a1060')
   ```

---

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert in Scylla's configuration, so feel free to point out a better approach.